# Photoisomerization of Azobenzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, orbitals, photochemistry

Rotation around the double bond of azobenzene is restricted because it would distort the P orbital overlap between the nitrogen atoms. However, in the $n \rightarrow \pi^*$ excited state ($S_1$), the rotation is no longer hindered and it can isomerize.

I don't understand why this is the case. You are taking an electron from the non-bonding orbital, and moving it into the pi-antibonding. However, the $\pi$-bonding is still present, so I see no reason why the rotation would be unrestrained. Is it something about the interaction between the electrons in the $\pi^*$ with the $\pi$ that weakens the double bond? And if so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Azobenzenes are one of the most widely used moietes in photochemically  switchable systems. Nevertheless, the pathways for the *E*-*Z* isomerisation of azobenzene in the $S_1$ and the $S_2$ state have been in debate for decades and I'm not quite sure whether this is finally solved.

> However, in the $n \rightarrow \pi^*$ excited state ($S_1$), the rotation is no longer hindered and it can isomerize.

Yes and no.

It is true that the $S_1$ state arises from a $n \rightarrow \pi^*$ transition in a weak, broad band with $\lambda_{\mathrm{max}} = 432\,\mathrm{nm}$ and $\epsilon \approx 400\,\mathrm{L\,mol^{-1}\,cm^{-1}}$ in hexane.

By the way, *E*-azobenzene exhibits another, much stronger absorption at $\lambda_{\mathrm{max}} = 319\,\mathrm{nm}$ with $\epsilon \approx 22800\,\mathrm{L\,mol^{-1}\,cm^{-1}}$ in the same solvent. This $\pi\rightarrow\pi^*$ transition to the $S_2$ state would indeed allow for an isomerisation through an **one-bond-flip** rotational mechanism.

(For the UV data, see [1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja01547a010) and [2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja038327y)).

But - *you saw that coming after this lengthy introduction* - the situation is much more complicated!

You have neglected the fact that *E*-*Z* isomerisations can proceed by other mechanisms than just the simple one-bond-flip that is usually postulated for alkenes!

Forgive me for not getting into all details on this, but for polyenes, to give an example, the so-called **Bicycle Pedal** (**BP**) and **Hula twist** (**HT**) pathways have been proposed and confirmed as space-conserving alternatives to the **one-bon-flip** mechanism. The latter can be visualized as *"let's just flip the other side of the former double bond around like a rotor"*.

Back to the azobenzenes. Even from more recent works ([2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja038327y), [3](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jp031149a), [4](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ncomms6860), [5](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3000008)), it seems that the *E*-*Z* isomerisation is still not fully explained, although a plain rotation around the former double bond can be excluded.

The two main fractions in the debate support mechanisms in which a contribution of **inversion** through a change of the $\ce{C-N-N}$ angle in the excited state is assumed. Whether this is the only effect and the reaction proceeds through a transition state with a linear $\ce{C-N-N}$ arrangement or whether an **inversion-assisted torsional pathway** provided the beter explanation is still unclear.

**References**

[1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja01547a010) George Zimmerman, Lue-Yung Chow, and Un-Jin Paik, *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1958**, *80*, 3528-3531.

[2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja038327y)  Alessandro Cembran, Fernando Bernardi, Marco Garavelli, Laura Gagliardi, and Giorgio Orlandi, *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **2004**, *126*, 3234-3243.

[3](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jp031149a) Eric Wei-Guang Diau, *J. Phys. Chem. A*, **2004**, *108*, 950-956.

[4](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ncomms6860) Eric M. M. Tan, Saeed Amirjalayer, Szymon Smolarek, Alexander Vdovin,    Francesco Zerbetto, and Wybren Jan Buma, *Nature Communications*, **2015**, *6*, Article number: 5860.

[5](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3000008) Junfeng Shao, Yibo Lei, Zhenyi Wen, Yusheng Dou, and Zhisong Wang, 
*J. Chem. Phys.*, **2008**, *129*, 164111

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much Klaus, this is very insightful. I will look into the papers and get further insight. I am curious to learn about the BP and HT pathways, and why they would occur in the S1 but not in the S0 state.

Comment: @Max BP and HT modes are usually discussed in the context of polyenes, think in double-bond homologues of  stilbenes. If you're interested in these, look for publications of Robert Liu, Jack Saltiel and Werner Fuß. As far as azobenzene is concerned, have a look at the references 2-4 and dig your way down from there. or, even, better, just use the azobenzene as building block in synthesis and don't care for the gory details ;-)

Comment: Thanks again for the advice! I'm looking into this for a molecular simulations class project, and the gory details are the most important part :)

Comment: Unless it is already among the references in the Nature article, http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3000008 might be interesting too.

Comment: I would like to encourage you to give the citations in addition to the DOI, I had to click all the links, just to find out, that I already read two of the papers. I also think proper acknowledgement, at least a name, is a treat in sciences.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン No problem. Done.