# Can different groups within a single molecule photoisomerize at different wavelengths?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, photochemistry

Azobenzene undergoes *trans → cis* photoisomerization when irradiated with light with a wavelength of 300–400 nm.

By adding electron withdrawing groups, the wavelength can be red-shifted.

If I were to make the molecule shown below, would it be possible to selectively photoisomerize around each of the $\ce{N=N}$ at different wavelengths?

[image: Proposed bis-diazo compound]

Comment: Yes you can increase wavelength  by substituents and by increasing conjugation length also,  for example a simple polyene such as  butadiene  vs.  carotene or  a substituted polyene such as retinal. But no, you cannot just excite one bond  in the whole conjugated part of the molecule. Using tailored femtosecond pulses there has been much effort to do 'bond selective' chemistry but what the results mean is still hotly disputed.

Comment: I don't remember the reference any more, but there was a way to have selectivity that was between _cis_- and _trans_- double bonds. I think as long as the energy difference is big enough relative to the spread in your input light, you should be able to have some selectivity. The only thing to watch out for is that as you increase substitution, you're going to start disfavoring the _cis_- form, which I gather is what you want to make.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31730/photoisomerization-of-azobenzene/31734

Comment: Thanks Porphyrin and Zhe. I am trying to design a photoswitchable ion binder for a supramolecular chemistry class. I am trying to design a way to 'lock' the molecule in a particular conformation using a thiol-disulfide dynamic interchange. I would like to be able to switch between which of the rings is locked to the other by using different wavelengths. Pretty far fetched idea, needs lots of refining, but it would be very nice to be able to rotate around a bond selectively.

Thanks again Klaus, I asked the azobenzene question the other time :) Still much to learn about photochemistry! :p

Comment: @zhe, yes its possible to selectively excite most cis and trans molecules as they generally have different absorption spectra. its doing that in the same molecule thas so far impossible.

Comment: *cis* and *trans* selectivity by wavelength, see for example [hemithioindigo](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tetlet.2015.05.022). Disclaimer: My former group.

Comment: @porphyrin I think I'm thinking too classically here. The entire conjugated system is going to be affected by substitution... :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory: **yes**

As soon as you have two distinct groups, you will have two different, discrete energy differences. If you manage to irradiate at exactly the correct wavelength, only one of the two will be excited.

In practice: **possibly, but it depends**

Two diazo groups are still rather similar. You will either need a beam that has a good wavelength focus or you will have to make their wavelengths sufficiently different.

By the way, note that both your average IR spectrum and your average UV/Vis spectrum show this property. At a specific wavelength, exactly *one* vibration (IR) or electron (UV/Vis) will be excited. With sufficient resolution, you should be able to excite the different nitro group vibrations separately. If this applies to one light wavelength band, it will work in others, too.

Comment: I think that you are not correct here, in the proposed molecule both cis and trans chromophores are in the same conjugation so are part of the same delocalised MO. If the were not connected electronically, say widely separated by a  alkyl chain, then only if cis & trans absorb at different wavelengths would it be possible to change the one with the lower energy  or longer wavelength. At shorter wavelengths where both absorb no discrimination would be possible. In solution levels are so broadened and are so overlapped that specific narrow band excitation has no particular effect.